# Where to place utilities in Python unittest test suites?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing unit tests for a largish piece of software written in Python, and there are some tools I wrote to facilitate tests. I would like to continue using these utilities in another test file.

The obvious solution is to put these utilities in a separate file next to the tests and load it, e.g.

```
import .utilities as tu
```

but that fails, because

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

which is fair enough.

So my question is: what is the recommended place to put utilities that are solely used for testing?

Comment: `import .utilities` is correct, assuming your package is defined correctly. Do you have all your tests in a proper package?

Comment: No, because I got the impression that making `tests` a package was somehow not right. Plenty of elaborate tutorials do not do that.

Comment: Such as? The `unittest` module in the standard library bases its test discovery on importable packages of tests.

Comment: For example here: https://plainenglish.io/blog/unit-testing-in-python-structure-57acd51da923

The tests are in a dir without package.

Comment: `tests/` basically *is* a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your project's name is `coolproj`. Assuming that you have the usual structure

```
coolproj -> coolproj -> __init__.py
                     -> file1.py
                     -> file2.py
                     -> ...
         -> tests -> __init__.py # You need to make `tests` a package!
                  -> utilities.py
                  -> test_file1.py
                  -> test_file2.py
                  -> ...
```

Then you can just import your `utilities` module in, say, `test_file1.py` via

```
from tests import utilities
```

and in the root directory `coolproj` (where you *should* be running your testsuite!) you can run all tests using the *test discovery* feature

```
python3 -m unittest
```

This should cover your question. By the way, in case your `utilities` module is not in `tests` but in `coolproj`, then the import should be

```
from coolproj import utilities
```

If for some reason you get the message `0 tests run`, then you may want to check how exactly you are naming your tests classes and members. In particular, the test discovery feature expects your test modules to be named `test_*.py`, as exemplified above. Follow the examples [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) to name your tests appropriately.

Comment: As for _where_ to put utilities that are solely used for testing, they should go in `tests`, as the scheme above shows. And don't forget your accompanying `test_utilities.py` module for extra caution :)